# Using Custom Redis Serializer from other project in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis

Currently, I have implemented a custom serializer based on `Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer` in a different project. When I defined this as `redisSerializerType="MyProjectLib.Core.Caching.Redis.RedisJsonSerializer,MyProjectLib.Core.Caching.Redis"`, I'm getting the below error.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyProjectLib.Core.Caching.Redis
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: MyProjectLib.Core.Caching.Redis | Domain ID: 2
```

How do I let the `web.config` to know about the assembly from `MyProjectLib` project? The project is included as reference project to my MVC project.